# How to get declared types using reflection

Tags: c#, nullable, system.reflection, propertyinfo

I am trying to get the declared type using reflection. It's working fine for non-nullable types, but failing for nullable types.

```
class Product
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal? OfferPrice { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = typeof(Product);
        var properties = t.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo price_pInfo = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.Name == "Price").FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Member 'Price' was defined as " + price_pInfo.PropertyType);


        PropertyInfo offerprice_pinfo = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.Name == "OfferPrice").FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Member 'OfferPrice' was defined as " + offerprice_pinfo.PropertyType);

    }
```

Output:

```
Member 'Price' was defined as System.Decimal
Member 'OfferPrice' was defined as System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal] //I am expecting to get Nullable<System.Decimal>
```

Comment: _"I am expecting to get Nullable<System.Decimal>"_ That's not the name of the type. The name the system returned to you is. If you want the name that you'd see in C# code, it's up to you to write the code to transform the name of the constructed type back to the C#-style name.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This question is specifically about nullable types. Because of its syntax, e.g `decimal?`, it may not be obvious to some that they're dealing with a generic class. For that reason I think this question has value to the community. Kindly consider re-opening.

Comment: @JeremyTCD: _"This question is specifically about nullable types"_ -- no, not really. It's about generic types, and the difference between the .NET name for constructed generic types vs the name C# programmers are used to seeing. It's exactly the same as the marked duplicate. To make matters worse, the answer you gave doesn't even accomplish what the author of the question has asked for, while the advice in the marked duplicate does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decimal?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<decimal>`, which is a *generic type*.  The runtime represents `Nullable<decimal>` as "System.Nullable`1[decimal]". From the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8):

> The name of a generic type ends with a backtick (`) followed by digits representing the number of generic type arguments. The purpose of this name mangling is to allow compilers to support generic types with the same name but with different numbers of type parameters, occurring in the same scope.

There is no built in way to retrieve a generic type's in-code representation, you'll have to manually edit the type name. Since you're only concerned about `Nullable<T>`:

```cs
public static string GetNullableTypeCodeRepresentation(string typeName)
{
    return Regex.Replace(typeName, @"\.Nullable`1\[(.*?)\]", ".Nullable<$1>");
}
```

Then:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type t = typeof(Product);
    var properties = t.GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo price_pInfo = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.Name == "Price").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("Member 'Price' was defined as " + price_pInfo.PropertyType);

    PropertyInfo offerprice_pinfo = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.Name == "OfferPrice").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("Member 'OfferPrice' was defined as " + GetNullableTypeCodeRepresentation(offerprice_pinfo.PropertyType.ToString()));
}
```

Prints:

```
Member 'Price' was defined as System.Decimal
Member 'OfferPrice' was defined as System.Nullable<System.Decimal>
```